# R Select Row By Ending Value

Tags: r, data.table, gsub

```
data=data.frame("grade"=c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
                "class"=c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
                "size"=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1),
                "var"=c('q33', 'q35', 'q39', 'q33', 'q35', 'q39'),
                "score"=c(5, 8, 7, 3, 7, 5))
```

If suppose I wish to subset data to exclude any row with 'var' ending in '5' how can I do this? Hopeful output:

```
data1=data.frame("grade"=c(1, 3, 1, 3),
                "class"=c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b'),
                "size"=c(1,2, 2, 1),
                "var"=c('q33', 'q39', 'q33', 'q39'),
                "score"=c(5, 7, 3,  5))
```

Comment: Take a look at the built-in function `endsWith`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `grepl` with `$` to specify the end of string

```
subset(data,  !grepl('5$', var))
#   grade class size var score
#1     1     a    1 q33     5
#3     3     a    2 q39     7
#4     1     b    2 q33     3
#6     3     b    1 q39     5
```

If we need to check for both first and last, use `^` to specify the start

```
subset(data, !grepl('^5|5$', var))
```

In this case, the start character is not digit, if we want to check the first occurrence of digit

```
subset(data, !grepl('\\D+5|5$', var))
```

Comment: grmbl.. just beat me to it...  `data[ grepl( "5$", data$var ), ] `

Comment: @akrun here is another thought just in case somebody could make use out of this. What if you wanted the same thing but instead of remove if the last value is 5, what if the first or first numeric was 5?

Answer (score 0):

As @Frank mentioned we can use built-in `endsWith` which requires a character input.

```
subset(data, !endsWith(var, "5"))

#  grade class size var score
#1     1     a    1 q33     5
#3     3     a    2 q39     7
#4     1     b    2 q33     3
#6     3     b    1 q39     5
```

**data**

```
data <- data.frame(grade=c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
                   class=c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
                   size=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1),
                   var=c('q33', 'q35', 'q39', 'q33', 'q35', 'q39'),
                   score=c(5, 8, 7, 3, 7, 5), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```